# About pointing devices

Tags: drivers

My friend is designing a pointing device which connects to the computer with Bluetooth and I want to know how to create software or drivers in order operate it like a mouse. if guys know anything about this, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth is a wireless protocol specification (thousand pages) A lot of pointing devices use a proprietary wireless protocol.  To do this, purchase a reference kit from a company like Cypress semiconductor.   This kit will contains hardware, software, and firmware sample code and I/O chips.  Way more than I can mention here.  Texas Instruments and Microchip have Bluetooth/802.15.4 kits too. Used zigbee wireless kits are on Ebay.  Hope that helps...